# Descripency in data received from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to fetch the likes count, share count, impression count etc for a given update.

We are using the endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/4822304/historical-status-update-statistics:(like-count,share-count,click-count,engagement,impression-count,time,comment-count)?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1517443200000&update-key=UPDATE-c4822304-6378756278751109120&format=json to fetch the same

For the same access token, the above endpoint is reporting 0 likes while another endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/4822304/updates/key=UPDATE-c4822304-6378756278751109120/likes?format=json is reporting 1 like.

Any ideas why this is happening?